# Install Magento 2 and add to Git and deploy and install on Staging server

Tags: magento2, installation, git, mamp

For my client I have to install **Magento 2** on a Staging server from a Git remote repo (on Beanstalk). So all the Magento code has to be deployable.

I see all kind of different approaches (comparing to Magento 1)? Where do I have to start and what workflow/strategy do I have to choose to make my code versionable in Git and deploy this code to the staging server?

I am working on a Mac. I also discovered some problems with Mamp and the MySQL version. Because Magento 2 requires MySQL 5.6.

I just want a good workflow so I can version my code and deploy it to the staging server.

Answer (score 0):

Git is god solution for development. But for staging/production better to have the same infrastructure. So, best solution for me it's use deployment base on Docker.

You develop you code, push it to git, run CI server that build docker and deploy it on staging.

Comment: thanks but I don't want to be dependent on another service. I just want to know how to install Magento 2 (composer / without composer??)? Built my theme and add all code to Git and deploy it to staging/production. For example: do I need a local environment to built my theme or can I built my theme on staging server?

Comment: [Here](https://alankent.me/2016/03/31/m2-project-source-code-management-recommendation/) is a suggestion from Magento's chief architect Alan Kent.